# referencing div from within iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, html

I'm developing a application where I need to write HTML/JS into a iframe. I chose a iframe because I thought that this would have it's own namespace etc, so I would not get into conflicts regarding JS-variable names etc.

But now, I try to reference a div, by it's ID, from within JS in the iframe. In the frame I have a button, that calls a function:

```
function colorDiv(){
  $("#test").css("background-color","red");
};
```

In the parent, this works - no problem. (Of course, this is a basic test-scenario. I want to write a graph in this div with highcharts. This is not working, and I am trying to figure out why not.)

But in the iframe, this does zip. The div does not get colored. The function is called, there is no error - but there is also no color...

(It might help to tell that there is a div called 'test' in the parent as well. But that does not color, and if I count the number of 'div#test' in the function colorDiv, it returns 1...
I also checked if jquery has been loaded, and it has...)

**Regarding the first two answers, I was not clear enough, maybe: I'm trying to change the div *within* the iFrame. Not in the parent window, but from a script in the iframe to a div within the same iframe. That's why I find it so surprising that this is not working....**

Can anybody shed some light on this? :)

regards,

Paul

Comment: Did you reference jquery from your iframe?

Answer (score 1):

*If i got topicstarter right* - you should **include jQuery libary again inside** html-page which is used inside the iframe, so that you could use it for manipulations inside child document

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call a DIV in the parent from within the iframe? You need to call the parent.$ instead:

```
parent.$("#test").css("background-color","red");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#test', top.document).css("background-color","red");
```

Or I do not understand your question?

Comment: clarified that I'm trying to change a div within the same iframe... So top.document will reference the parent of the iFrame, which is not what I want to change...

Answer (score 0):

```
function colorDiv(){
  window.opener.$("#test").css("background-color","red");
};
```